# DPI Dependent OSM Tile Rendering

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, resolution, scale-factor

We have built an OSM Tile Server following the instructions at

http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/

The tile server is rendering tiles, but the street names on the tiles are 
not readable on high DPI devices, e.g. Nexus 6 at 2560×1440 493dpi.

We would like to modify the tile server so it generates tiles based upon the 
client screen's DPI. For example changing the request URL to include a 
DPI parameter, e.g.

http://mytileserver.com/osm/client-dpi/12/1050/1522.png

Please let us know how this might be accomplished?